# change the value of a property inside one object with the value of a property from another object that is inside an array

Tags: arrays, dictionary, ecmascript-6

I have this object

```
{id: 4450, name: "product name", stock_status: "IN_STOCK", item: 32}
```

and this array of objects

```
[{value: "31", label: "1"}, {value: "32", label: "2"}]
```

Is there a simple way in es6 to match the "item" property from the first object to the "value" property of an object in the array and return the first object with the value of "label" replacing the value of item like this:

```
{id: 4450, name: "product name", stock_status: "IN_STOCK", item: "2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful, if you use the spread operator

```
const obj = {id: 4450, name: "product name", stock_status: "IN_STOCK", item: 32}
const arr = [{value: "31", label: "1"}, {value: "32", label: "2"}]

// arr[i] 'i' is index of object in array
let newObj = { ...obj, item: (arr[1].label)}
```